# how to make minipage align perfectly at the top

Tags: minipage

I am completely new to Latex, and I am having issues aligning two components widthwise across the page on my resume. Here is a screenshot of my problem:
[image]
although it may or may not be obvious in this screenshot, the bar below education is just a slight bit lower than the bar below skills and it is driving me crazy. Here is my latex code

```
\documentclass[]{resume-openfont}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Convenience command - make it easy to fill template

% Create job position command. Parameters: company, position, location, when
\newcommand{\resumeHeading}[4]{\runsubsection{#1}\descript{ | #2}\hfill\location{#3 | #4}\fakeNewLine\NoSpace}

% Create education heading. Parameters: Name, degree, location, when
\newcommand{\educationHeading}[4]{\runsubsection{#1}  \location{#3 | #4}\\
\descript{#2}\fakeNewLine}

% Parameters: courses
\newcommand{\courseWork}[1]{\semiBold{Relevant Coursework:} #1}

% Parameters: courses
\newcommand{\teacherAssistant}[1]{\semiBold{Teacher Assistant (TA):} #1}

% Command to create smaller heading: Parameters: title, when
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[2]{\minorSection{#1}\hfill\location{#2}\fakeNewLine\NoSpace}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\section{Skills}
\textcolor{ProcessBlue}{\rule{8.5 cm}{1mm}} 
\begin{resumeSkillList}
    \small{\item{
    \doubleItem{Languages:}{Python, C, Java, Racket, HTML, CSS, Javascript}%
    {}{}
    \\
    \doubleItem{Technologies:}{Git, ReactJS, Firebase}%
    {}{}
    }}
\end{resumeSkillList}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\section{Education}
\textcolor{ProcessBlue}{\rule{8cm}{1mm}} \newline
\educationHeading{University of Bananaland}{BSc. Banana , GPA: banana \%}{}{2020-2025}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Remark:** I cannot run your code because on Overleaf (TeXLive), the `resume-openfont` class seems not to be available.

Comment: **Guess:** Can you att `\strut` in both sections? `\section{\strut Skills}` and `\section{\strut Education}`

Comment: **Erratum:** "att" should be "add" :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, I am using the following latex template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-deedy/cxtjgrmpsrvh on overleaf, so im not sure how to fix that. As for adding \strut, I am getting the following error: https://imgur.com/a/9zPKW6R . Thank you for your help regardless!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. My short and probably not useful answer is to not use the template and to use a "better" template that needs less micro-tuning, especially for beginners like you. I personally used (and paid for) `https://zety.com/` for my last professional CV (was recommended in the German magazine c't).